# How to prevent a download from stopping when Nintendo Switch screen goes black?

Tags: nintendo-switch

Whenever my screen turns black on the switch (it isn't docked) the download stops.  I have sleep mode disabled, but that didn't fix it.

When the screen turns back on, the download resumes and says it will take something like 10 hours to finish because it sees that in the past 5 minutes or whatever no progress has been made.  How do I solve this?

Comment: Could any of those [steps](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Nintendo-Switch/Troubleshooting/Download-Does-Not-Progress-While-in-Sleep-Mode-2041186.html) help?